# How to see which IP address is "bigger"

Tags: vb.net, compare, ip-address

If I had a IP address range (e.g. 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.255) and I was counting up (say incrementing by a random number), how could I determine whether I've gone past the range?

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Even if this is Q&A, could you introduce the above as true question and not as an announcement?

Comment: Sure. The Q&A system is confusing. It shouldn't give me both the question and the answer box in one screen. I don't know what (or what not) to put where.

Comment: @user287848 When you [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), there's a single input box for your question. Once posted, the answer box is displayed below your post.

Comment: Please amend your post to only include the question; you may answer your own question (and are actually encouraged to do so!), but it also gives others the chance to provide answers.

Comment: Oh, you literally want me to make up a question, as if I had one... Seems a bit unnecessary.

Comment: It is also highly unnecessary to downvote my posts due to this issue. I'm trying to be helpful, yet I'm getting flak for semantics. I could understand if it was more than this, especially if the content itself is not helpful.

Comment: There _is_ a Code Review forum if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Nope, not really. I'm having a hard time understanding why everyone is confused with my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply convert the IP addresses to numbers and compare the numbers.

```
    Dim ipmax As Net.IPAddress = Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.255")
    Dim ip1 As Net.IPAddress = Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.0")

    Dim ipmaxAsNum As UInt32 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(ipmax.GetAddressBytes.Reverse.ToArray, 0)
    Dim ip1AsNum As UInt32 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(ip1.GetAddressBytes.Reverse.ToArray, 0)

    If ip1AsNum > ipmaxAsNum Then
        Stop
    Else
        Stop
    End If
```

Comment: Ugh, how could I forget about BitConverter. This is the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
           '''<summary>Checks if IP Address A is larger than IP Address B. Returns True if A is larger, returns False if B is larger.</summary>

Private Function Check_If_Larger(ByVal IP_Address_A As Net.IPAddress, ByVal IP_Address_B As Net.IPAddress) As Boolean
    Dim IP_Address_A_Split() As String = IP_Address_A.ToString.Split("."c)
    Dim IP_Address_B_Split() As String = IP_Address_B.ToString.Split("."c)
    Dim IP_Address_A_Score As Integer = 0
    Dim IP_Address_B_Score As Integer = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To IP_Address_A_Split.Length - 1
        If Convert.ToInt32(IP_Address_A_Split(i)) > Convert.ToInt32(IP_Address_B_Split(i)) Then
            IP_Address_A_Score += 1
        ElseIf Convert.ToInt32(IP_Address_B_Split(i)) > Convert.ToInt32(IP_Address_A_Split(i)) Then
            IP_Address_B_Score += 1
        End If
    Next
    If IP_Address_A_Score > IP_Address_B_Score Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a hierarchy of values in ip addresses, which gets bigger from right to left. i.e. the leftmost values are more important than rightmost values and have more impact in the size of the ip address. E.g. 192.168.1.0 is bigger than 192.168.0.255

Assigning scores based on their hierarchies would help. E.g.

```
Private Function Max(A As String, B As String) As String
    Dim AA() As String = A.Split(".")
    Dim BB() As String = B.Split(".")
    Dim A_Score As Integer = 0
    Dim B_Score As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To AA.Length - 1
        If AA(i) > BB(i) Then
            A_Score += AA.Length - i
        ElseIf BB(i) > AA(i) Then
            B_Score += BB.Length - i
        End If
    Next
    If A_Score > B_Score Then
        Return A
    ElseIf B_Score > A_Score Then
        Return B
    Else
        Return ""
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Correct. Originally I was trying to make a score system. I took a break, came back, forgot, and finished the rest.